# Sed pattern for multiple lines

Tags: linux, shell, regex, sed

I want to remove all create table statements from a mysql script, but the statement runs over multiple lines.

Like this: `Create table ......NEWLINE... NEWLINE... NEWLINE....;`

So I tried this statement, but nothing happens:

```
sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE(.*\n)*.*;`//' *.sql
```

Seq only reads one line at a time? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will delete all lines between the lines containing `CREATE TABLE` and `;`

```
sed -i '/CREATE TABLE/,/;/d' copy/dump.sql
```